# Trying to cycle out old logs in nodeJS still writes to cycled out file

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

So i've written a service that checks for possible existing logs and if theyre there, renames it with an increasing integer and then adds a new log to write to, like so:

```
async function moveLogs( path, i ){
    if( i == 10 ){
        fs.unlinkSync( path + '.' + i )
    } else {
        let j = i + 1
        if( fs.existsSync( path + '.' + j ) ) {
            await moveLogs( path, j )
        }

        // Then move the log
        if( i == 0 ){
            await fs.renameSync( path, path+'.'+j )
            makeFile( path )     // Make new empty file if doesnt exist
        } else {
            await fs.renameSync( path+'.'+i, path+'.'+j )
        }
    }
}
```

However, the service that is writing out to the log is still writing to the old, now renamed, log.
the logger is a homebrew logger which uses fs.createWriteStream on initialisation and then writes to the file whenever the attached write funciton is called:

```
class Log_Wrap{

    constructor( min_level, critical = false ){
        if( critical ){
            this.log   = fs.createWriteStream( process.env.CRITICAL_PATH + min_level.toLowerCase() + '.log', {flags : 'a'})
        } else {
            this.log   = fs.createWriteStream( process.env.LOG_PATH + min_level.toLowerCase() + '.log', {flags : 'a'})
        }
        var lev    = [ true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true ]
        for (var i = 0; i < log_level.indexOf( min_level.toUpperCase() ); i++){
            lev[i] = false
        }
        this.level = lev
    }
}

...

    _write( functionName, level, ...out ) {         
        this.log.write( '[' + moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') + '] ' + functionName + '.' + level.toUpperCase() + ': ' )
        out.forEach( term => { 
            this.log.write( util.format( term ) ) } )
        this.log.write( '\n' )
    }
```

and then the Logger is an object that contains an array of Log_Wrap's, and writes using:

```
write( level, functionName, ...out ){
    for( var i = 0; i < this.loggers.length; i++ ){
       if ( this.loggers[i].canLog( level.toUpperCase() ) ){
            this.loggers[i]._write( functionName, level, ...out )
       }
    }
}
```

So I guess the question is:
Should I restructure how the logger works, or is there a way to cycle out the log being written to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handle that the logger uses (`this.log`) points to a location on disc. Once you rename the file, the location on disk won't be accessible with the old name anymore, but whoever already has a handle to there will continue writing and reading. That is until all handles are dropped.
This askUbuntu may answer your wonders: https://askubuntu.com/questions/347371/is-it-100-safe-to-rename-a-file-while-its-being-written

You could try checking in the logger every once in a while if the file is still there: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback

Comment: Thanks Valery, just a quick question, I only remove the file if it's 10 iterations back, how do I check to see if the file has been renamed and therefore change the file pointed at?

Comment: You could probably go around fs.watch() somehow (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) or maybe some checking of the `ctime` of the file and the one, when you created your write stream (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_options_callback)